# NullPointerException on JerseyTest.target

Tags: java, spring, testing, controller, jersey

I'm trying to test controller with Jersey and get NullPointerExcetion on target().

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <slf4j.version>1.7.26</slf4j.version>
        <persistence-api.version>1.0.2</persistence-api.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <ojdbc6.version>11.2.0.4</ojdbc6.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>${persistence-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hamcrest assertions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AssertJ assertions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc6.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and test class

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

public class EndpointTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(Endpoint.class);
    }

    @Test
    void whenTestThenOK() {
        Response response = target("/endpoint")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.json("{}"));

        Assertions.assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());

    }
}
```

On javax.ws.rs-api version 2.0.1, there was a NoClassDefFoundError error on javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider. I changed it to 2.1 and now I get NPE.

Also, I tried to add other dependencies, change versions, but even such a simple test cannot be run

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected body (json entity)? Try with at least one...

```
.post(Entity.json("{"name":"value"}"));
```

It seems that you are sending (post) an empty body.

Comment: I added body, but it still doesn't works :(